# Setting flink in HA using zookepeer

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zookeeper, flink-streaming

I have 2 jobmanager running in kubenetes. I have 5 zookeeper nodes also running in kubenetetes. My flink config for each of job manager looks like this.

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: some-us-east-1-dev2-project-jobmanager
high-availability: zookeeper
high-availability.zookeeper.quorum: zk-0.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-1.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-2.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-3.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2181,zk-4.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2181
high-availability.zookeeper.path.root: /flink
high-availability.cluster-id: /i-project-dev2
high-availability.storageDir: s3a://a-some-events-useast1-admin/ha/project/dev2/
high-availability.jobmanager.port: 6150
high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl: open
zookeeper.sasl.disable: true
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
```

and my `zoo.cfg` is

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
dataDir=/bitnami/zookeeper/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
autopurge.purgeInterval=24

## Metrics Providers
#
# https://prometheus.io Metrics Exporter
metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider
metricsProvider.httpPort=9141
metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true
preAllocSize=65536
snapCount=100000
maxCnxns=0
reconfigEnabled=false
quorumListenOnAllIPs=false
4lw.commands.whitelist=srvr, mntr, ruok, stat
maxSessionTimeout=60000
admin.serverPort=8080
admin.enableServer=true
server.1=zk-0.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
server.2=zk-1.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
server.3=zk-2.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
server.4=zk-3.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
server.5=zk-4.zk-headless.flink.svc.cluster.local:2888:3888;2181
```

Job manager pod some up fine, but the flink web ui fails with `service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. please refresh.`

So far i have tried,

1. restart zookeeper cluster by deleting zookeeper deployment in k8 and redeploying it.
2. used deleteall on the `/flink/i-project-dev2` and then restarting the zookeeper by killing each pod.
3. Logs in flink and zookeeper show nothing related leader election. In zookeeper logs i can see some debug message, but nothing related to any error.
4. restart jobmanager pods by deleting them in k8s

How to I get this resolve such that flink web ui can run.